# the show error in this program cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, xml

What does this error mean ?

My code image

[image]

Comment: it is framelayout id in mainactivity.xml

Comment: that means that you don't have such id. (obvious?)

Comment: MainActivity.java and content_main is a .xml file.

Comment: @DJRachitMaliksahab if it is layout then you should use `R.layout.content_main`, instead of `R.id.content_main` for layouts

Comment: Show your layout

Comment: if i change R.layout.content_main then application unfortunlity stopped.

Answer (score 2):

Place a frame layout in xml and put the id of the frame layout as `R.id.content_frame`